# Prerender.io not working when redirecting root path with apache mod rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, prerender

I am trying to redirect my root path www.example.com to www.example.com/en/
But when I use this the root path for prerender redirects too.

So for example when I go to this `www.example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=` it redirects directly to `www.example.com/en/` instead of `www.example.com/en/?_escaped_fragment_=`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/en/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Please help thank you.

Comment: Did you try without the redirect? `[L]` instead of `[L,R=301]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is expected and working correctly.

If a user goes to `www.example.com/` then they should get redirected to `www.example.com/en/`.

So if a crawler goes to `www.example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=` then they should also get redirected to `www.example.com/en/`.

The crawler will update their index and they will eventually crawl `www.example.com/en`. If they find the meta fragment tag then they will crawl `www.example.com/en/?_escaped_fragment_=`.

So that's just all part of the process of the escaped fragment crawling scheme.